# Outlook.com Sweep rule vs Filter rule

Tags: outlook.com

New outlook.com introduced new sweep option. With it, you can create a filter to move messages from particular sender to a particular folder after certain days the mail comes. This rules gets added to the Filter list. However we cannot edit this rule by clicking Edit in front of it in that list. The dialog appears saying you should delete the rule and create the new one.

I don't understand why sweep rules are considered differently from Filter rules?

I have 68 filter rules. What if I want to add such time clause to these filter rules so that instead of moving the incoming mails immediately to a certain folder, they will be kept in Inbox for say 10 days and then they will be moved. Such time clause cannot be added to the filter rules. So should I delete all these 68 filters and create new Sweep rules?